# Best way to call a generic function n times with n types

Tags: scala

I need to call a generic function n times with n different types. Is it possible to loop through a list of types and call the function with each type inside the loop instead of writing n function call statements? If not, is there any other succinct way?

Sample code:

```scala
// Now
function[Type1]()
function[Type2]()
…
function[Typen]()

// Want something like this
val types = List(Type1, Type2, …, Typen)
for (type <- types) {
    function[type]()
}
```

Comment: Perhaps TypeTags could help you here? I'm not sure it's the best thing to do, though

Comment: Why not just make a list of the functions? The use-case here is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1: if the function doesn't accept an implicit argument depending on the type parameter, something like `def function[A]()(implicit foo: Foo[A])`, then the calls can't actually do anything different and you can write it as

```
for (_ <- 0 to n) {
  function[SomeArbitraryType]()
}
```

Case 2: if it does, then make a list of the implicit parameters and call the function on them:

```
val foos = List(implicitly[Foo[Type1]], ...)

for (foo <- foos) {
  function()(foo)
}
```

If the above fails to compile because it can't figure out the type parameter, you can cheat:

```
val foos = List(implicitly[Foo[Type1]].asInstanceOf[Foo[Any]], ...)
```

This way the type parameter of `function()(foo)` will be inferred as `Any` but again it can't actually matter for the execution of the function; only the value of the implicit parameter does.

There may be a convenience function to get the implicit value such as `classTag` for `ClassTag`s but calling `implicitly` will work for any `Foo`.

In conclusion: type erasure is your best friend here.

EDIT: of course, case 2 ends up being more code than you had initially but it may be more reasonable if your function actually has non-implicit arguments which are the same for each call.